# Ошибка Web сервиса C#

Tags: c#

При запуске уже опубликованной веб-службы получаю такую ошибку:

> Описание: Ошибка при разборе ресурса, требуемого для обслуживания
>   этого запроса. Изучите следующие подробные сведения о данной ошибке
>   разбора и измените исходный файл.

Сообщение об ошибке синтаксического анализатора:

> Не удалось создать тип 'NewDealer.NewDealer'.

Ошибка источника:

> Строка 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="NewDealer.asmx.cs"
>   Class="NewDealer.NewDealer" %>
>
> Исходный файл: /DealerService/NewDealer.asmx    Строка: 1
>
> Информация о версии: Платформа Microsoft .NET Framework,
>   версия:4.0.30319; ASP.NET, версия:4.7.2558.0

Прошу помочь

Comment: А в службу поддержки хостера вы обращались?

Comment: Это все эксперимент на локальном IIS

Comment: Звучит так, будто у вашего класса `NewDealer`  нет конструктора без параметров и потому среда не может создать его экземпляр

Comment: ну, или тут `Class="NewDealer.NewDealer"` у вас что то не так. У вас неймспейс совпадает с именем класса?

Comment: Да, все честно в неймспэйсах

Comment: Пока проблема не решена

Comment: Применил конструктор без параметров, та же ситуация. Не помогло

Comment: Web-службу делаю первый раз, на локальном IIS, ОС Windows 8.1

Comment: Не понял, какой файл?

Comment: Файл `NewDealer.cs` должен быть или в корне, или в папке App_Code (в зависимости от конфигурации) Попробуйте положите файл туда, или туда. Если "ничего не помагает" - соберите проэкт полностью, а в шапке укажите dll, и приберите метку "CodeFile"

Comment: Да, этот файл как раз в корне

Comment: Не помогло пока что

Comment: 'NewDealer.asmx.cs' лежит рядом с 'NewDealer.asmx'?

Comment: Если ничего не помагает - откажитесть от "компиляции". Соберите программу сами в студии, положите `your_dll.dll` из рилиза в папку bin и поменяйте строку  `<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="NewDealer.NewDealer,your_dll" %>` убрав с неё CodeBehind и указав имя модуля.

Comment: Имеется ввиду от Публикации веб сервера через Студию отказаться?

Comment: Нет, публикация работает иногда кривовато. Она не убирает атрибут  CodeBehind, уберите атрибут - укажите либу (скорее всего `Class="NewDealer.NewDealer,DealerService"`) и будет счастье

Comment: Пока результат нулевой

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался, в чем дело:

1) В диспетчере IIS становимся на папку приложения, в котором прописана наша веб-служба

2) Right-click мыши на папке, добавляем виртуальный каталог, задаем ему Alias, совпадающий с именем Веб-службы

3) Становимся на созданный виртуальный каталог, Right-click, и выбираем "Convert To application".

При условии что права пользователя, под которым работает Пул приложений, имеют полный доступ к каталогу Веб-службы (проверить), все работает чудесно. 
Всем спасибо